# Deleting Core Data objects with relationships

Tags: ios, core-data

Being new to CoreData and still learning the proper practices I am having trouble correctly deleting Core data objects that have a relationship associated to it. While the action of deleting an object is happening correctly, it is not 100%.

I am deleting an object of entity type 'TripDestination' that has a One to Many relationship with entity 'Trip'. I.e a trip has many tripDestinations but a tripDestination can only associate to one trip.

'TripDestinations' are displayed in a table and can be deleted via UITableView's delegate methods and is done so correctly. However since a FetchRequest is performed on every ViewWillAppear of the view, the object that was deleted reappears but displays a null value.

It is now that I will mention the delete rule of a 'TripDestination' is set to Nullify.

**The objective is to be able to delete the object completely from CoreData memory instead of setting the objects value to null as the delete rule is doing.**

**Edit**

```
if editingStyle == .Delete {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    managedContext.deleteObject(destinations[indexPath.row])

    do {
        try managedContext.save()

    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    destinations.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

The delete rule for tripDestination on Trip is also nullify however I understand it should be cascade. I haven't implemented this yet because I haven't implemented delete functionality on Trip objects (but yes I know I should have already done this).

Comment: I believe you did `managedObjectContext.save()`?

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController will help you out tremendously with this kind of thing (i.e. fetching NSManagedObjects and being notified if the NSManagedObjectContext changes). Will you please provide the code that you've used to delete the NSManagedObject in the UITableViewDelegate method? Also, what is the delete rule for the tipDestinations relationship on Trip?

Comment: @zcui93 yes thats correct.

Comment: @Jonathan please see edited question. I agree with your first line of comment, I have this as a task to complete for myself. Appreciate the note though.

Comment: Please go in to the object editor and change the delete rule for the tripDestinations relationship on the Trip entity to cascade and re-run your code.

Comment: @Jonathan seemed to work now as well as me changing minor error in the code. Many thanks.

Comment: Right on! No problem. I'm glad I could help.